# Write C# Code In VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to write this code in VB.NET:

```
ModernIpg.PaymentWebServiceService ModernService = new ModernIpg.PaymentWebServiceService();
ModernService.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
ModernIpg.loginRequest req = new ModernIpg.loginRequest();
req.username = username;
req.password = password;

string Session_ID = ModernService.login(req);

ModernIpg.wsContext context = new ModernIpg.wsContext() { data = new ModernIpg.wsContextEntry[1] };
context.data[0] = new ModernIpg.wsContextEntry();
context.data[0].key = "SESSION_ID";
context.data[0].value = Session_ID;
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Try converter.telerik.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find It:

```
Dim ModernService As ModernIpg.PaymentWebServiceService = New ModernIpg.PaymentWebServiceService()
        ModernService.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        Dim req As ModernIpg.loginRequest = New ModernIpg.loginRequest()
        req.username = Username
        req.password = Password

        Dim Session_ID As String = ModernService.login(req)

        Dim oWscontext As ModernIpg.wsContext = New ModernIpg.wsContext() With {.data = New ModernIpg.wsContextEntry(0) {}}


        oWscontext.data(0) = New ModernIpg.wsContextEntry()
        oWscontext.data(0).key = "Session_ID"
        oWscontext.data(0).value = Session_ID
```

Comment: Changing the constructor parameter from one to zero will create errors.  The one must stay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
        Dim ModernService As New ModernIpg.PaymentWebServiceService()
        ModernService.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        Dim req As ModernIpg.loginRequest = New ModernIpg.loginRequest()
        req.username = username
        req.password = password

        Dim Session_ID As String = ModernService.login(req)

        Dim context As ModernIpg.wsContext = new ModernIpg.wsContext() { data = new ModernIpg.wsContextEntry(1) }
        context.data(0) = New ModernIpg.wsContextEntry()
        context.data(0).key = "SESSION_ID"
        context.data(0).value = Session_ID​
```

The code should look something like this

```css
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim context As ModernIpg.wsContext = New ModernIpg.wsContext() With {.data = New ModernIpg.wsContextEntry(1)}

    End Sub

End Module
Public Class ModernIpg
    Public Class wsContext
        Public data As wsContextEntry
    End Class
    Public Class wsContextEntry
        Sub New(x As Integer)

        End Sub
    End Class
End Class​
```

Comment: Thanks. But Not Work. this line has error:
Dim context As ModernIpg.wsContext = new ModernIpg.wsContext() { data = new ModernIpg.wsContextEntry(1) }

Comment: Should be this : Dim context As ModernIpg.wsContext = New ModernIpg.wsContext() With {.data = New ModernIpg.wsContextEntry(1)}